# How to provide Detail and Summary objects for my REST api with Node.js and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

I want to provide some venue information over my node.js REST API build by mongoose and express.

In my model, I should take care of every details for a venue.

But when requested for summary, I should show only some of them.

And If requested for 1 venue in detail, I should show more.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve something like this why not create some custom queries for your detail and summary actions?

Basically what you need to do.

1. Create your custom queries that received the custom data.Do this in your model. (e.g the data for summary or details)
2. Create specific actions for these speficic type of API calls in your controllers and server it as you wish. (E.g create /getVenueDetail/venueId=213235 )